# MS Access SQL : How to create 2 columns filled with different filters from another column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Unfortunately, I have to work on a very badly built table.
Here is what it looks like:

[init table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbxsL.png)

| Product-code | Criteria | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10184149 | Blue Grid | 12.0 |
| 10184149 | Red Grid | 13.0 |

I've tried several approaches but I just can't seem to get it right, like :

```
SELECT 
    IIF(([public_report_product].[Criteria]="Blue Grid"),
         [public_report_product].[Value]) AS Blue_Grid,
    IIF(([public_report_product].[Criteria]="Red Grid"),
         [public_report_product].[Value],Null) AS Red_Grid,
    public_dosa.product_code
FROM 
    public_report_product 
INNER JOIN 
    public_dosa ON public_dosa.product_code) = public_report_product.[Product code]
WHERE 
    public_report_product.[Criteria] = "Blue Grid" OR 
    public_report_product.[Criteria] = "Red Grid";
```

I have of course many other lines with the same "Product code" in this table.

I would like something like this as a result:

[Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHGHl.png)

| Product-code | Blue Grid | Red Grid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10184149 | 12.0 | 13.0 |

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you have in TEXT, and what you would like to have in TEXT.

Comment: SEE: no need for pictures .... 

Comment: Sorry to have disturbed you with my pictures. I take note of your remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this would be to use a [crosstab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) query like this:

```sql
TRANSFORM First(Table.Value) AS Value
SELECT Table.product_code
FROM Table
GROUP BY Table.product_code
PIVOT Table.Criteria;
```

Comment: I managed to get what I was looking for with your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    max(IIf((prp.[Criteria]="Blue Grid"),prp.[Value], null)) AS Blue_Grid, 
    max(IIf((prp.[Criteria]="Red Grid"),prp.[Value],Null)) AS Red_Grid, 
    pd.product_code
FROM public_report_product prp
   INNER JOIN public_dosa pd ON pd.product_code = prp.[Product code]
WHERE prp.[Criteria] in ("Blue Grid","Red Grid")
group by pd.product_code;
```

(While access have weird non-ANSI SQL support, this should even work in access)